# WPF Clear UserControl's children

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a UserControl in WPF, and the UserControl works so that when the user moves mouse over the control, it's childcontrols should be removed, but I don't seem to find the Children property or anything like that..

XAML is here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         Name="thisTextBox"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="57"     MouseEnter="UserControl_MouseEnter_1" MouseLeave="UserControl_MouseLeave_1">
<TextBlock Name="TypeText" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" />
</UserControl>
```

And in code I need to do something like this to get the TextBlock go away:

```
private void UserControl_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     Children.Clear(); // There is no such thing as children here!!!
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "child element" of the UserControl is contained in the [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) property. You can set it to `null` in order to remove the content.

```
private void UserControl_MouseEnter_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Content = null;
}
```

Comment: Be very careful when doing this, as it could cause a memory leak.

Having a child that is referenced by another object you are expecting to clear with setting it's parent to null will not always clear the child.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that if an object has external references, setting it's parent reference will not dispose the child object.

That means a memory leak.

I was agreeing with you, but with a 'just be sure you've not added it to another collection in the meantime' - hence the be careful comment.

Comment: That's an assumption.  Anyway, go ahead, have your leaky code.  I'm not going to argue about it.

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your comment, other than to make me look like I'm talking to nobody.

Comment: I disagree, setting something to null and assuming it's clearing the object is entirely relevant to the conversation.  I was just warning, you made it an issue out of misplaced relevancy.

Comment: In case you've got something to warn about, be clear and precise about the circumstances or conditions under which your warning applies. Your "Having a child that is referenced by another object you are expecting to clear with setting it's parent to null will not always clear the child" is of no help at all, as it explains nothing. Again, write another answer and elaborate on the scenarios of possible memory leaks.

Comment: You are not quoting me when you say "Having a child that is referenced by another object you are expecting to clear with setting it's parent to null will not always clear the child"

So you obviously got what I meant, stop being obtuse and trying to turn it so you are right - regardless of your statement, you were clearly wrong, which is probably why you redacted your comments.

Semantics won't help you.

Comment: I have on numerous occasions written about this, I was just being  as helpful as I can be, it appears you are being a pedant which is REALLY not helpful.

One statement to warn them in a helpful manner and you rant about it's not appropriate - who made you the captain of what appropriate in a thread?

Please be more accommodating and not try to belittle people, the 12k score doesn't apply.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to get unfriendly here. I am trying to be accommodating by asking you to give people a comprehensible example of what you're talking about. If you've got one at hand, write another answer, otherwise it's just talking. Saying "I have on numerous occasions written about this" is pointless. Who will ever realize that you did that? At least, provide a link to what you've written!